# Burning a disc into a desktop

Tags: windows-10

When burning a disc
It give me 2 option and I choose the Like a USB Flash Drive and burn my videos in my disc..
Does my disc will read on any cd/dvd player even though I choose the Like a USB Foash Drive?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Namely... Which disk? Burning what files? With which software tool? Please edit the question accordingly and describe exactly what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

No, to have your disk reproduced by a CD/DVD player you must burn the files in groups that is select "With a CD/DVD Player" option when prompted during the burning wizard.

[image]

Otherwise, your disk will be used as a live file system and allows you to access your file as any other removable media.
Live Help is available clicking "Which one should i choose?" just below the radio button choice.

Source: [Windows Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/burn-a-disc-how-do-you-want-to-use-this-disc-like/6c054aca-8233-442e-ada2-6da1a6a7ad8c)